# Hidden communities not working in "community" menu

Tags: support, hidden-communities

My hidden communities are not working as expected, see attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

It seems the 4 sites: Meta, Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu and Unix & Linux are "stuck" in the community drop-down menu in the top right corner. No matter which communities I hide or unhide, these 4 stick to the menu and can't be changed.

As of this moment, the Android community should also be visible, but it isn't. I've tried clearing cookies for the sites, but to no avail.

So anyone know what this is about?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not what "hiding" does. Hiding a community means that it's not visible to *other users* but it still remains visible to you.

If you want to remove a site from your site switcher favorite communities, click the (easily-missed) "edit" button and remove it manually.

Comment: Oh thanks - I somehow thought there was a connection between hiding and the menu - but I see that's not the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The drop down on the top right can only be seen by you, so hidden communities have nothing to do with it. Hidden communities affect what is shown on your profile page.

You can click on “edit” next to ”my communities” to change what you see in the upper right drop down. By default I think it will show the top 4-5 communities where you have the most reputation.